# Issue - img in textcontent div in ExtJS

Tags: jquery, dom, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a simple question for you. I've a template and I want to change inside when ondblclick.

`<div id="item-{#}"> Item {#}
    <img src="remove.png" id="close" onclick="$(this).parent().remove()"/>
</div>`

`Ext.get("item-{#}").dom.textContent`

When I write this to console.log its answer is " Item {#} " as normal.

This is my function;

`Ext.Msg.prompt('Change Note','Change your note',function(btn,text){
    if (btn=='ok') {
       elVal.dom.textContent = text;
     }
},null,true,elVal.dom.textContent);`

After clicking to 'ok' button, the text is changing successfully but my remove.png is also removing itself. Why is it removing img tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct manipulation of DOM elements is not a common practice in ExtJS. The library abstracts from the underlying html to a great degree.

In the case of templates, you would call `tpl.overwrite(target, data)` if you only have tpl (instance of XTemplate) or `panel.update(data)` if the template is `tpl` config option of the panel.

Also, it looks like you're using combination of jQuery ($ variable) and ExtJS - that is usually not necessary as Ext can do everything jQuery can plus much more.

As to listeners (click), it shouldn't be installed as in html tag as "onclick" attribute. Best is to install the listener on the container by standard Ext function `on`.